# Undefined variable: $errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

i try show errors after validate a form.

i use this code on the view:

```
@if($errors->has())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <div>{{ $error }}</div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

and in the controller:

```
public function searchActivity(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'search' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required_with:search|required|date|after:yesterday'
    ]);

    return view(App::getLocale() . '.activities.ActivityResults');

}
```

but dont work.

What could be happening?

note: i use Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Please show routes file contents.

Comment: The above is going to throw an error because `has()` requires a field name.

Comment: If you're getting `Undefined variable: $error` please could show the stack trace for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The has method may be used to determine if any error messages exist
>   for a given field:

```
if ($errors->has('email')) {
    //
}
```

So we can check like

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Ref Link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: We did the same but getting the same error! `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors' in /var/www/html/app/storage/framework/views/3f4c02587ea10e202b71a319d212cd2acd6d6647.php`

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the "Undefined variable: $errors...", check your routes and ensure that the route has the "web" middleware assigned to it. Check your route list:

```
 php artisan route:list
```

As you can see from the sample output below, the admin routes do not have the "web" middleware assigned to it:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/home                              | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                                 | cors,auth
  |
|        | POST      | admin/login                             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                           | cors,guest
  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/login                             | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                   | cors,guest
  |
|        | POST      | admin/logout                            | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                          | cors
```

As mentioned by @patricus [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434174/4040835):

> The $errors variable is made available to the views in the
>   Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware. This
>   middleware is included in the web middleware group by default.
>
> If your route is not using the web middleware group, make sure that
>   whatever group it is in includes this middleware (along with
>   Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession, since the errors are
>   stored in the session).

To fix this, wrap the affected routes in your routes/web.php or routes/api.php within a group and assign the "web" middleware to the group, like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

Then check again:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Sample output:

```
|        | POST      | admin/login                             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                           | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/login                             | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                   | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | POST      | admin/logout                            | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                          | cors,web
  |
|        | POST      | admin/password/email                    | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail     | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | POST      | admin/password/reset                    | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                   | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/password/reset                    | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm    | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/password/reset/{token}            | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm           | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | POST      | admin/register                          |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                     | cors,web,guest
  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/register                          | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm         | cors,web,guest
```

Answer (score 1):

use `@if($errors->any())` instead of `@if($errors->has())`
and if this could help this code works well with me

```
@if(!empty($errors))
    @if($errors->any())
        <ul class="alert alert-danger" style="list-style-type: none">
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better use a front end validator like **jqueryValidator.**
Because to validate this form you have to turn off the Javascript in your browser.Then it will sometimes damage your work in loading datatables or related js works inside your project.

But if u are using a backend validation this may help you to understand it better.

Here, in the blade:

```
@if(!$errors->isEmpty())
    <div class="alert alert-danger ">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>

          <div class="error">
               {{--@if(isset($errors))--}}
                   {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('confirmPassword') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('FirstName') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('LastName') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('JoinDate') }}
                   {{ $errors->first('dob') }}
           </div>
    </div>
    @endif
```

And in the created request class inside the **rule()** function

`return [
         'email'    =>  'required|between:3,64|email|unique:employees',
         'password' =>'required|min:5|max:10',
         'confirmPassword' =>'required|same:password',
          'FirstName' =>'required',
          'JoinDate' =>'required|after:dob',
          'LastName' =>'required',
          'dob' =>'required',
        ];`

Answer (score 1):

@patricus made very good answer.

You can append 'web' middleware to your routes and all errors will appear in view:

```
Route::get('path', Controller::class .'@method')->middleware(['web']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@foreach($errors as $error)
```

{{ $error}}}

@endforeach

I use this syntax for error

Comment: You can write it either way.

Answer (score 0):

The `$errors` variable is made available to the views in the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware. This middleware is included in the `web` middleware group by default.

If your route is not using the `web` middleware group, make sure that whatever group it is in includes this middleware (along with `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`, since the errors are stored in the session).